# How to fetch main, sub and child categories from three tables. PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, categories

i am working on a project, in which i want to use Categories and their Sub and Child categories, i've created 3 tables ( MainCats, SubCats, ChildCats ). 
now i want to fetch data from those tables and want to store in  option of HTML.
Here is code PHP, MYSQLI and HTML code.

```
$cat_fetch = "SELECT  categories, sub_categories, child_categories FROM categories.maincatSd, sub_categories.subcat_name, child_categories.child_cat_name";
            $cat_run = mysqli_query($con, $cat_fetch);
             echo "<option value='' >ڪيٽيگري چونڊيو</option>";
             if(mysqli_num_rows($cat_run) >0){
                 while($cat_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_run)){
                     $cat_name = $cat_row['child_cat_name'];
                     $cat_name = $cat_row['subcat_name'];
                     $cat_name = $cat_row['maincatSd'];

                     //$cat_name = $cat_row['subcat_name'];



                     echo "<option value='".$cat_name."' ".((isset($Catagory) and $Catagory == $cat_name)?"selected":"")." >".ucfirst($cat_name)."</option>";
                             }

                         }else{
                                echo "<option name='Catagory' tabindex='2' id='Catagory' value=''>NoCat</option>";       
                         }
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: the result is fetched only one table's data.

Comment: It's not what one would call a pretty nice DB structure :/ (as picture shows). You link sub_cat to main_cat, pretty ok, but then, sub_child is linked to ?... you should have a look at [MySQL foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) as it could help you link all tables, all data, and get all results in one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of your given image.. I don't feel you need to maintain any kind of relation at the time of fetching records from tables. It just needs to fetch records from those three tables & build the options list & print show on the web page. If that's exactly what you want, then check out this.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Connect to DB
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'host', 'password', 'DB_Name');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: Failed to make a MySQL connection, here is why: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

// ---Fetch all main category records---
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_cat";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$totRecordsMainCat= array();
if($result->num_rows){
    while($dataSource = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $totRecordsMainCat[] = $dataSource;
    }
}

// ---Fetch all Sub category records---
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_cat";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$totRecordsSubCat= array();
if($result->num_rows){
    while($dataSource = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $totRecordsSubCat[] = $dataSource;
    }
}

// ---Fetch all Child category records---
$sql = "SELECT * FROM child_cat";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$totRecordsChildCat= array();
if($result->num_rows){
    while($dataSource = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $totRecordsChildCat[] = $dataSource;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo "<select>";
        echo "<option value=''>Select Category</option>";

        foreach ($totRecordsMainCat as $key => $value)
        {
            $cat_name = $value['cat_name'];
            echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
        }

        foreach ($totRecordsSubCat as $key => $value)
        {
            $cat_name = $value['subcat_name'];
            echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
        }

        foreach ($totRecordsChildCat as $key => $value)
        {
            $cat_name = $value['childcat_name'];
            echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it using 3 different queries and nested loops..

```
SELECT * FROM main_cat
// Loop query result
   SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE sub_cat_id = main_cat_id
   // Loop query result
      SELECT * FROM child_cat WHERE child_cat_id = sub_cat_id
      // Loop query results
```

Comment: i don't want to join them, just want to retrieve all values of categories in option.